# Spring JMS MessageListenerContainer along with JmsPoolConnectionFactory Question

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I need your help to understand the properties of a `JmsPoolConnectionFactory` and `MessageListenerContainer`.

This my `MessageListenerContainer` Configuration

```kotlin
    @Bean
    @Suppress("MagicNumber")
    fun messageListenerContainer(
        connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory,
        messageListener: MyMessageListener,
        queueName: QueueNameFunction
    ): org.springframework.jms.listener.MessageListenerContainer = org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.DefaultMessageListenerContainer()
        .apply {
            this.maxConcurrentConsumers = 5
            this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory
            this.destinationName = queueName("my-service-name", "my-queue-name")
            this.messageListener = messageListener
            this.sessionAcknowledgeMode = CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
        }
```

This my `jmsConnectionFactory` configuration

```
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    fun jmsConnectionFactory(
        properties: ActiveMQProperties
    ): org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory =
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactoryFactory.JmsPoolConnectionFactoryFactory(
            createJmsPoolConnectionFactoryProperties()
        ).createPooledConnectionFactory(
            org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                properties.user,
                properties.password,
                properties.brokerUrl
            )
        )

    @Suppress("MagicNumber")
    private fun createJmsPoolConnectionFactoryProperties() = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactoryProperties.JmsPoolConnectionFactoryProperties().apply {
        isEnabled = true // Spring Default is false
        isBlockIfFull = true // Spring Default is true
        blockIfFullTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(-1) Spring Default is -1 millisecond
        idleTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(30) Spring Default is 30 Seconds
        maxConnections = 10 // Spring default is 1
        maxSessionsPerConnection = 500 // Spring Default is 500
        timeBetweenExpirationCheck = Duration.ofMillis(-1) // Spring Default is -1
        isUseAnonymousProducers = true // # Spring Default is true
    }
```

As soon as I change the timeBetweenExpirationCheck to something that makes sense to me, for example 60 seconds

this warning is logged

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'my-service-name.my-queue-name' - trying to recover. Cause: The Consumer is closed
```

Can you explain what is happening here? I think I understand, but I want to confirm.

I have 3 other questions:

- Is it a good approach to have a `MessageListenerContainer` with `pooledConnections` where there is more than one connection?
- If yes, is it a good approach to have a `connectionPool` with no `expirationCheck`?
- If you say **no**, it is not good to have a pooledConnection with more then one connection and no `expirationCheck` how must I configure the `MessageListenerContainer` to work with `pooledConnections`?

Thank you very much for helping me understand this.